# Best way to determine if a file is empty (php)?

Tags: php

I'm including a custom.css file in my template to allow site owners to add their own css rules. However, when I ship the file, its empty and there's no sense loading it if they've not added any rules to it.

What's the best way to determine if its empty?

```
if ( 0 == filesize( $file_path ) )
{
    // file is empty
}

// OR:

if ( '' == file_get_contents( $file_path ) )
{
    // file is empty
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` will read the whole file while `filesize()` uses `stat()` to determine the file size. Use `filesize()`, it should consume less disk I/O and much less memory.

Comment: ...and consume much less memory

Comment: Just wanna point out that if the file is changing call clearstatcache() before calling filesize() or you will get cached results. This happened to me.

Answer (score 26):

Everybody be carefull when using `filesize`, cause it's results are cached for better performance. So if you need better precision, it is recommended to use something like:

```
<?
clearstatcache();
if(filesize($path_to_your_file)) {
    // your file is not empty
}
```

[More info here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

Comment: This won't work because the manual explicitly states that `filesize` parameter must be a string. `fopen` returns a resource.

Comment: @Nicero, thanks, you're right. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 10):

Using `filesize()` is clearly better. It uses `stat()` which doesn't have to open the file at all.

`file_get_contents()` reads the whole file.. imagine what happens if you have a 10GB file.

Comment: Imagine how long your website would take to load with a 10GB CSS file :P

Comment: I imagine, after further thought, there's probably less harm in just loading an empty css than going to the trouble of testing if its empty to avoid loading it.

Comment: For small files (haven't read the CSS part) it doesn't really matter. filesize() is still faster and much better though - why would you want to actually read the file's contents from the harddisk if the inode (or even the filesystem's cache or PHP's internal stat-cache) contains all informations you need.

Comment: @ThieMaster The only reason I can think of is to determine if the CSS file actually contains information worth loading. If it is full of whitespace only, for example, there is not much point including it. I guess it is one of those speed/accuracy trade offs. +1 anyway for useful info.

Comment: Simply do that when saving it: Strip comments and trim() it. If it's empty, don't save it at all.

Comment: @ThieMaster That would be ideal, but the OP says `I'm including a custom.css file in my template to allow site owners to add their own css rules` sounds like the file is edited directly.

Comment: If the file is loaded from remote, both filesize and file_get_contents are bad even though filesize will probably just do a HTTP HEAD request.. but still nothing you'll want.

Answer (score 5):

`filesize()` would be more efficient, however, it could be misleading.  If someone were to just have comments in there or even just whitespace...it would make the filesize larger.  IMO you should instead look for something specific in the file, like `/* enabled=true */` on the first line and then use fopen/fread to just read the first line.  If it's not there, don't load it.

Comment: nothing bad, however, in false result. this check is not that important

Comment: true...but neither is it a big deal to just load the file if it's empty.  Just sayin'...if you're gonna nickel and dime something like loading an empty file, you may as well count this as "important" too

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, `filesize` is the way to go *for local files*. Many stream wrappers on the other hand, including HTTP, do *not* have `stat()` support, thus `filesize` will fail, whereas `file_get_contents` will work.