# IF file is !empty ELSE

Tags: php, if-statement

So, if i have a file that when its empty it requires a specific function, but if the file is NOT empty it will proceed to show (else) something else. This is currently the format I am using. I have tired several different manners and variations of doing so (from PHP Manual examples to StackOverFlow Q/A). What it is doing is showing me the else not the if, since the file is actually empty...

```
<?
$file = 'config/config2.php';

if(!empty($file))
{
some code here!
}
else
{
some other code here!
}
?>
```

Comment: the file is empty (filesize() =0) or the STRING $file is empty ??

Comment: $file which is the file (config/config2.php) is empty.

Comment: `$file` is just a string. You're not reading any files in this code.

Comment: `filesize()` will return the size of a file

Comment: Your code is asking if the variable `$file` has a value or not, essentially. It is jumping to the `else` because `$file` is not empty, it has a value of `config/config2.php`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4857194/1415724

Comment: So i should change it to ` $file = 'config/config2.php` and add `filesize($file)` ?

Comment: `if (filesize("file.txt") == 0) { // do something }`

Comment: Yeah. Dagon's answer below looks alright to me.

Comment: So i did `if(filesize($file)!=0)` and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Great stuff. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct when you can! Also, I'm not really sure why people are downvoting your question. It's clear, you've shown your code and some effort to get it working. Just because it's a simple thing for some people, it doesn't mean it's deserving of a downvote.

Comment: @j.otero `if(!empty` are usually reserved for POST/GET variables in forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?
$file = 'config/config2.php';

if(filesize($file)!=0)// NB:an empty 'looking' file could have a file size above 0
{
some code here!
}
else
{
some other code here!
}
?>
```

Comment: *"NB:an empty 'looking' file could have a file size above 0"* - for example, a BOM.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be that you are not actually loading the file before you check if it is empty.

You are only setting the variable $file to the string 'config/config2.php' not actually loading the file.

Before running your if statement do this:

`$file = file_get_contents('config/config2.php');`

or look into this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: dont load a whole file in to memory just to check if it is empty

Comment: I was under an assumption that the file was intended to be used