# Check if the text file was empty

Tags: php, explode

I'd like to know how to check if a text file is empty or not. It means that there is no text even some space, i.e. it was blank

```
function keyRemain($path)
{
    $ambil = file_get_contents("data/$path/keywords.txt");
    $kw = explode(",", $ambil);
    if (count($kw) > 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to check the empty function along with trim

```
function keyRemain($path)
{
    $ambil = trim(file_get_contents("data/$path/keywords.txt"));
    var_dump($ambil); // check the output here
    if(!empty($ambil)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: using filesize  is a mistake. White spaces will count size.

Comment: @rafi the second option will have to work, have you tried var_dump on `$ambil` variable just before if condition?

Comment: @RafiHalilintar `trim` should work if the file just contains white spaces only, i.e there is no new line for example.

Comment: @pravindot17 i have try to dump it, it still blank there is no value even not showing the var type.

Comment: @SaidbakR so it can't read the empty file ? i think it has another way.. let me figure it out.. Thanks btw for share your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this was not the answer, just the another way to check the file. Before this was happend, the code appear instead the class. After i cut it and move it outside of the class it work perfectly without any errors.

Answer (score -1):

> file_get_contents() will read the whole file while filesize() uses stat() to detirmine the file size. Use filesize(), it should consume less disk I/O.

That's the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857182/best-way-to-determine-if-a-file-is-empty-php), on stack...

You can also (on same link there's this answer):

```
clearstatcache();
if(filesize($path_to_your_file)) {
    // your file is not empty
}
```

Comment: File size is not an option for this requirement. some spaces will make size greater than zero.