# PHP form validation of uploaded file

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm having trouble validating a file upload in php. Basically the code doesn't see that the files are empty, I've been looking at it all afternoon and can't figure it out. I'm sure it's something simple. If somebody could solve my problem I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.....

ps. this is in an unfinished project, I'm just stuck at the validation stage.

```
<?php
    // Link to separate file that holds the connection info
    include 'connection.php';

    $error = "";

    if ($_POST){

        // Back up to JS Validation
        if(!$_POST['username']){
            $error = "No username<br>";
        }
        if(!$_POST['password']){
            $error .= "No password<br>";
        }
        if(!$_POST['email']){
           $error .= "No email<br>";
        }

        // Test to see if a file has been posted
        if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
            // Set the upload path
            $path = "uploads/";
            // Append the filename
            $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

            // Need to move the file to folder
            // If successful display success message or error
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
                // File has been uploaded create user
                $query = "INSERT INTO ";
            } else {
                // File not uploaded, account not created
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, You have not create an account";
            }
        } else {
            $error .= "No file uploaded";
        }
    } 
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>

        h2 {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        .signupContainer {
            background-color: darkgray;
            width: 400px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .alertContainer {         
            width: 400px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .signupFormContainer {
            padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
            margin: auto; 
        }

    </style>

    <title>NotePad App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2 class="text-center">NotePad App</h2>  

    <?php
      // Back up to JS validation - display errors
      if ($error){
          ?>
            <div class="alertContainer">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <strong>Error!</strong> There were errors on your form:<br><?php echo $error ?>
                </div>
            </div>
          <?php
      }

    ?>

    <div class="signupContainer">
        <div class="signupFormContainer">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST" id="createUser">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Create a Username" name="username">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please enter a username
                  </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter a Password" name="password">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please enter a password
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Email Address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please enter a valid email address
                  </div>
              </div>  
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Upload Text File</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file" accept="text/plain">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please select a txt file
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group text-center">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="signup">Sign Up!</button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript">

        function clearClass(){
            $("#username").removeClass("is-invalid");
            $("#password").removeClass("is-invalid");
            $("#email").removeClass("is-invalid");
             $("#uploaded_file").removeClass("is-invalid");
        }

        $("#signup").click(function(){

            clearClass();
            var frmError = false;

//            if ($("#username").val() == ""){
//                $("#username").addClass("is-invalid");
//                frmError = true;
//            }
//            if ($("#password").val() == ""){
//                $("#password").addClass("is-invalid");
//                frmError = true;
//            }
//            if ($("#email").val() == ""){
//                $("#email").addClass("is-invalid");
//                frmError = true;
//            }
//            if ($("#uploaded_file").val() == ""){
//                $("#uploaded_file").addClass("is-invalid");
//                frmError = true;
//            }

            if (!frmError){
                $('#createUser').submit();
            }
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4857194/9025311

Comment: Not 100% sure about that post, I need to know whether I file exists or not. Not whether it has a file size or not?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Neil did you solve it or not?

Comment: Not yet, Im not at my desk at the moment. Cheers

Comment: Solved, thanks, you changed my line of though! Changed to look at the file name.... 
`if (!$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']){
            $error .= "No file uploaded";
        } `

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'No upload';
}
```

Returns TRUE if the file named by filename was uploaded via HTTP POST. This is useful to help ensure that a malicious user hasn't tried to trick the script into working on files upon which it should not be working--for instance, /etc/passwd.

```
bool is_uploaded_file ( string $filename )
```

For proper working, the `function is_uploaded_file()` needs an argument like `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`, - the name of the uploaded file on the client's machine `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` does not work.
You can check the documentation for [mroe](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)