# fgets a UTF-8 txt file returns rubbish letters and true when file is blank

Tags: php, file

I assume that this is due to the UTF-8 txt file format. The txt file is totally empty and when I tried `fgets($file_handle)`, I get these rubbish letters:

[image: These weird letters]

How do I fix this? I want to check if the file is empty by using:

```
if ( !$file_data = fgets($file_handle) )
    // This code runs if file is empty
```

**EDIT**

This is a new file using encoding UTF-8:

[image: New File]

Comment: Check out this answer for better ways to check if a file is empty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857182/best-way-to-determine-if-a-file-is-empty-php

Comment: @Bananaapple `file_get_contents()` gives me the same rubbish letters. `file_size` returns `2` when it's totally blank. Both are not really viable, are they? How do I know that the size is gonna be `2` when it's clearly empty? What if it's like `4` or `16`?

Comment: All this suggests that while the file appears empty it is in fact not. Try creating an empty file and testing against that - `touch somefilename` on linux based systems. I would expect that to correctly show as empty so really what you want to look at is not why the empty check fails but why your file has data in it.

Comment: @Bananaapple I've just created a new file again with encoding UTF-8. Look at the picture I've inserted in my OP. It's 1KB in size **even when it's a new file**. I've also mentioned that I suspect this is because of the encoding UTF-8 (now I'm pretty sure it is).

Comment: How exactly are you creating your files? If it's through PHP it would probably help to add the relevant code to your question :-)

Comment: @Bananaapple It was created using Notepad. I saved the file normally and changed the encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the BOM ([Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) added by Notepad to detect the encoding:

> Microsoft compilers and interpreters, and many pieces of software on Microsoft Windows such as Notepad treat the BOM as a required magic number rather than use heuristics. These tools add a BOM when saving text as UTF-8, and cannot interpret UTF-8 unless the BOM is present or the file contains only ASCII. Google Docs also adds a BOM when converting a document to a plain text file for download.

From this article you can also see that:

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`

We should therefore be able to write a PHP function to account for this:

```
function is_utf8_file_empty($filename)
{
    $file = @fopen($filename, "r");
    $bom  = fread($file, filesize($filename));

    if ($bom == b"\xEF\xBB\xBF") {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Do be aware that this is specific for files created in the manner you described and this is just example code - you should definitely test this and possible modify it to allow it to better handle large files / files that are completely empty etc

Comment: Very interesting., from the link you provided above, I presume that if I were to deal with UTF-16, I'd have to check for these: `0xFE 0xFF`?

Comment: There seem to be different BOMs for UTF-16 depending on the endianness so probably best to trial and error it against a UTF-16 file you intend to use or alternatively code it to be able to cope with all variations.

Comment: I see. That's kind of a hassle. Nevertheless, thank you for the answer! Have a good day.